# Queries for null or empty strings

Tags: solr, querybuilder

I tried to apply exactly what is on the following link to query fields with null or empty strings
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/queries-for-null-or-empty-strings.html

In fact, solr doesn't return the field in the results if it is empty or null.

So, Is there something missing to check?

Thanks in advance for the help,

Comment: You can take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238609/how-to-query-solr-for-empty-fields

Comment: Could you please share some more details, such as what you want to achieve and how you are doing it? Did you perform reindexing after performing steps from the link?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat. Yes, I did re-indexing. Simply, I need to query a list of items that have an empty value for a specific field. For example, I need to get all blog items with an empty title. For that, I applied what is in https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/queries-for-null-or-empty-strings.html